# BlockEQ wallet does not open. What to do?

Tags: xlm

Today I wanted to open a BlockEQ wallet on my Mac. A window will open, but it is completely white and nothing more. For BlockEQ wallet, I have only 12 phrases and a PIN code. What to do? How can I see my XLM coins?